# PHP sql database, inserting UNIQUE values

Tags: php, mysql

Im working with sql database (phpMyadmin) and with programming language PHP.
I've got a table with data e.g:

T1:
145
138.8
110.6
1759.4
1400.9
1891.4
1755.4
1760.4

T2:
141.9
110.6
1400.9
1891.4
1758.4

My question > 
Is there existing sql syntax, that is able to average values which are lying in ONE THRESHOLD (like > 1755.4,1760.4,1759.4 OR 145,138.8) and INSERT THEM  AS UNIQUE VALUES to another table ?

What I need is create T2(contain UNIQUE values) from T1, and INSERTING them only if they didn't exist in T2.

I was trying, to looping throw 2 arrays (1starray = T1 and 2ndarray = T2 ) too. And compare data in array1 and array2, and trying to insert values which can be unique.

```
for($z = 0; $z<$numberApp; $z++) { 
while($j<$numberAbs-1){
     $Abs=$arrayabs[$j];
     $state_change = (abs($Abs - abs($previous_Abs)));
      if ($state_change>100){
        $instantChange = True;
        echo "<br>"." better than tolerance: " . $instantChange;
             }
     else  {
      $instantChange = False;
       echo "<br>"." lower than tolerance" . $instantChange;
     }

     //if($state_change = (abs($some_item - $previous_item)<= $tolerance)){
     if($Abs != $previous_Abs){
      echo "<br>" ."   some_item : "  .$Abs."   previous_item : "  .$previous_Abs;
     }

     //$lastAbs=$arrayabs[$j];
     //echo "  next_item : " .$lastAbs;

      if ($instantChange == True and $onChange == False){
      $Abs2 [] = $podiel;
      $finalPower = $podiel;
      }
     if ($instantChange){
        $D=0;
        echo "ABSOLUT >>> " .$lastAbs;
 $percentual1 = ($power_app[$z] * 0.9);
  $percentual2 = ($power_app[$z] * 1.1);

 if(($lastAbs<$percentual1 || $lastAbs>$percentual2)){
     $user = 'root';
      $pass = 'password';
      $db = 'vypis';
      //if($N>0){
$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die();
      $sql = "INSERT INTO vypis.nilm_app2(power) VALUES ('$lastAbs')";

       if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){

    echo "Records added successfully.";

} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);

}
}
//$power_app[$z++];
      }
```

Thank you for everyone, who going to help, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO vypis.nilm_zar2(id,power) SELECT DISTINCT T1.id,T1.power FROM vypis.nilm AS T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 2 FROM vypis.nilm_zar2 AS T2 WHERE T2.power NOT IN ((T1.power * 0.9),(T1.power * 1.1)))";                                                                                                       I was trying my problem to solve with that insert above, but it inserting all values from T1: vypis.nilm into T2.vypis.nilm_zar2. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math here sounds complex enough that you're probably better off doing the complex stuff (averaging the values and determining whether a value is unique) *in PHP*, then finishing off with a couple simple MySQL statements.

This can probably be done in pure MySQL with a bit of trickery, but frequently it isn't worth the time and complexity it creates. (Imagine you'll have to debug that monster SQL query six months from now!)

By contrast, it's trivial to take a handful of values in PHP and average them; it's also trivial to run a quick MySQL query to determine whether a value is unique. So if you're unsure how to mash these together into one big SQL statement, start out by just handling them in the PHP code as separate steps! Then later on, if performance issues come up, you can think about how to combine them (but at least by that point you already have something that works).